# nagios network analyzer and dell Force10 switch monitoring in sFlow

Tags: monitoring, nagios, traffic, switching, network-analysis

I setup nagios network analyzer and trying to monitor a Dell Force10 switch, i enabled sflow in Force10 side as follows:

```
DELL-S4048-K13#show sflow
sFlow services are enabled
Egress Management Interface sFlow services are disabled
Global default sampling rate: 256
Global default counter polling interval: 15
Global default extended maximum header size: 256 bytes
Global extended information enabled: switch
2  collectors configured
Collector IP addr: 10.62.73.158, Agent IP addr: 10.62.91.245, UDP port: 6343 
VRF: Default
Collector IP addr: 10.32.98.202, Agent IP addr: 10.62.91.245, UDP port: 6343 
VRF: Default
0 UDP packets exported
357 UDP packets dropped
0 sFlow samples collected

stack-unit 1 Port set 0 
  Te 1/1: configured rate 256, actual rate 256
  Te 1/2: configured rate 256, actual rate 256
```

In nagios NA server i'm trying to add a source, in type of sFlow, with IP and port of Dell Force10 enter.

Unluckly no data is collected.

Anyone has success experience in monitor a Dell Force10 switch in Nagios?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

finally i did it via 
http://www.dell.com/support/article/uk/en/ukbsdt1/how11008/how-to-set-up-sflow-on-dell-networking-force10-switches?lang=en

the key command is 
`sflow extended-switch enable`